# How to make an android button rapidly change collors on click?

Tags: java, android

I want to make a knowledge quiz game for Android, and so far I haven't been having any major problems. I already have all the buttons set, and what I need is to animate them so that when they get clicked a red or green color (depending on whether the answer is wright or wrong) will start flashing over the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Animation class

```
    final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
    animation.setDuration(500); // duration - half a second
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // do not alter animation rate
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // Repeat animation infinitely
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // Reverse animation at the end so the button will fade back in
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_btn);
    btn.startAnimation(animation);
```

Courtesy : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4852468/931982

Comment: No, this is not what I was asking. Alpha animation makes the view dissapear and appear on certain time intervals. What I want is the button to change it's background color to green, and then back to the default black, and then back to green... So it looks like it's flashing.

Comment: @DavidSimka ok .. what will be interval of changing background? from red to green again to red?

Comment: I am guessing 200 miliseconds, but I still haven't decided. I just want to know the way of making something like that, once I know it, I will make the animation to my liking.

Comment: you can use a timer then.. in timer on each tick you can alternate the image