# Animation-Performance in ListView Items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I want a blink animation on a ImageView which is part of a ListView item. I.e. i have a simple LinearLayout with a ImageView on the left and a TextView on the right. Now have some of the Items a blinking ImageView and some not. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852281/android-how-can-i-make-a-button-flash/4852468#4852468) solution for a blink animation but i don't know if this solution is to much for the ui thread. My ListView can contains like 100 Items and for example 30 of them can have this blink animation.

Is there some best practice for ListView Items which contain animations? It would be really helpful if someone has a good idea or hint/note about this topic.

Comment: Its good to use Alpha Animation for blinking. It will not take so much load in UI thread. Then after if it is necessary then you can use it in Handler.

Comment: Thank you. Any infos about view recycling during animation?

Comment: Why do you want to recycle views during animation. Your views can be recycle using ViewHolder class in getView() method of your custom adapter.

Comment: Sorry, what i mean is can a view be recycled if some animations run on it. I recognize in this moment, that the animation runs not on the list item and this means it can be recyled. Sorry for the confusion