# How to make a button blink a set amount of times?

Tags: java, android

I want to make a button blink a set ammount of times, but without editing the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
     android:duration="600" android:repeatMode="reverse"  
     android:repeatCount="1" />
</set>
```

Comment: maybe it help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852281/android-how-can-i-make-a-button-flash

Comment: have you thought and flirting with this ? = android:repeatCount="1"

Comment: Actually, I can not change that XML in any way, I need to use it for other stuff in the code, what I'm looking for here is a way to make it repeat for a limited amount of times, defined in the java code(let's say make it blink 2 or 3 times).